# Preg_match on JS variable with random name

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I would like to get value from JS variable by PHP function preg_match (because source is external website downloaded by *file_get_contents*).

How it looks, example:

> var dates_012fbb32db259a64dfe333a8538fd6zz = ['2015-08-26','2015-08-27','2015-08-28','2015-08-31','2015-09-01'];

I want get full value of this variable or if possible last element eg. 2015-09-01

What important part "012fbb32db259a64dfe333a8538fd6zz" is random every refresh.

I tried build pattern by myself but not working:

```
$pattern = '/var dates_^[a-zA-Z0-9]+ = "(.*)";/';       
preg_match($pattern, $source_website, $result);
```

Comment: There are no double quotes in your example string

Comment: Also why do you have `^` in there?

Comment: You are right. I'm idiot. After remove what u said script working. How ever do you know how to select only the last value? fun with str_replace?

Comment: Like this: [`'/var dates_[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*=\s*\[(?:,?'([^']*)')+/'`](https://regex101.com/r/uN7kZ3/2). It will be in Group 1. But you already have a similar answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will return your last element in offset 1

```
$pattern = "/var dates_[a-zA-Z0-9]{32} = .*\'([\d]{4}\-[\d]{2}\-[\d]{2})'\];/";
```

$result[1] will have the result.
NOTE: I have considered the random number to be 32 bit. if not then you can use [a-zA-Z0-9]+ in place of {32}